# Is it possible to have different status bar colors in the splash screen vs main app in an Android app?

Tags: android, react-native

I have a splash screen with a black background that I'd like to have a matching black status bar for. However, once a user is in the app, I want it to be white in light mode and black in dark mode.

Right now, my files are set up as follows:

`values/colors.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<resources>
  <color name="splashscreen_background">#000000</color>
  <color name="iconBackground">#000000</color>
  <color name="colorPrimary">#FFFFFF</color>
  <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

`values-nights/colors.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<resources>
    <color name="splashscreen_background">#000000</color>
    <color name="iconBackground">#000000</color>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#000000</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

`values/styles.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/ResetEditText</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
  </style>
  <style name="ResetEditText" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#c8c8c8</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
  </style>
  <style name="SplashScreen" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

`AndroidManifest.xml` (just the relevant section)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.package.packagename">
  <application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
      android:launchMode="singleTask"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
      android:theme="@style/SplashScreen"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
      ...
```

With the thinking being that the splash screen would set the primary dark to the dark value, but the main app theme would use the white value. Unfortunately, it seems both the splash and main app are just using the white value right now...

Answer (score 0):

You can change the status bar color programmatically in your splash activity `onCreate()` or fragment `onViewCreated()` method.

Here is a java code to changing status bar color dynamically :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        int currentNightMode = getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;

        if (currentNightMode == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES) {

            final Window window = getWindow();
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(0);
            window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.SPLASH_BLACK));

        } else if (currentNightMode == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.MAIN_WHITE));
        }

    }
```

And you can add these lines to your app theme in `styles.xml` file :

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="m">true</item>
<item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/nav_bar_color</item>
```

Comment: Is it not possible to do this purely with the styles and colors files? I'm also using React Native so I'm not sure what the equivalent changes would be

Comment: @Johnny Yes you can. you should define two separated themes. one for your Splash Screen and the other for rest of your app screens. you can define themes in your `styles.xml` file. then in your `manifest.xml` use the Splash theme for your Splash activity and use Main theme for your app default theme.

Comment: Hmm isn't that how it's set up already, with the separate splash style in styles.xml? I'll add a bit of my manifest into my post as well for more context